# Problem interating through associative xml in action script

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript

I have a swf file embedded in a html, it displays some data loaded from an URL containg a xml:

```
   a_xml = new AssociativeXML();
   a_xml.load("https://myURL.com");
```

The link contains a xml having this structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<parent>
    <infoblock>
       <block>
           <title>title</title> 
           <content>content</content> 
       </block>
      <block>
           <title>title</title> 
           <content>content</content> 
      </block>
    </infoblock>
    <body>
      <type>
         <typename>typename0</typename> 
         <content>
               <description>description</description> 
         </content>
      </type>
      <type>
         <typename>typename1</typename> 
         <content>
              <description>description</description>
         </content>
      </type>
      <others>others</others> 
    </body>
  </parent>
```

The problem is that flash is not reading the entire xml properly. I have a Action Script method which gets the data from the xml like:

```
text = this.parent.infoblock.block[0].title.nodeValue
```

But it's getting stuck at the second "type" node, which somehow is read as null and flash is printing "undefined" instead. This is how I access it:

```
this.parent.body.type[0].typename.nodeValue // returns typename0
this.parent.body.type[1].typename.nodeValue //returns undefined
```

So flash can read half of the xml an the other half it sees empty.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: The XML is not well-formed - it's missing a </body> end tag. If the XML is written by you it should be a simple matter of fixing this on your end. But if the XML is coming from an external source...

Comment: Hi, the real xml used is fine, I just forgot to add the </body> end tag here in the structure example. I will edit the post, thanks!

Comment: The script looks fine, however... You are working with E4X traversing here. The **parent.body.type** notation produces an **XMLList** object with who-knows-what inside. You should iterate over the elements of this object to learn things about it: how many elements go there, what their indices are, etc. You might (or you might not) be surprised, but AS3 E4X had its bugs over the player's versions so the result you get might actually depend on the target player you are compiling to.

Comment: I was able to solve the issue by replacing the "this" word with the actual name of the xml variable: a_xml.parent.body.type[1].tyname.nodeValue. Why it worked for the first block and the other ones not, beats me, but this approach did it.